# Problem adding quotes to SQL inside Python

Tags: python, sql, formatting, format

I want to add quotes i.e. '' around my input_date in the following sql query.

```
sql = "select num_store, sum(gross_sales) as gross_sales from dtm.sales where day = " + input_date + " and num_store = '" + store + "' GROUP BY num_store"
```

The dates I am querying on are of type ANSIDATE. I want to add the '' around the input date as cleanly as possible so that it would still detect the fields.

The query that I am running directly on the vectorwise database using SQuirrel SQL CLient to verify is like so:

```
SELECT num_store, sum(gross_sales) as gross_sales FROM dtm.sales WHERE day = '2019-06-21' AND num_store = 69 GROUP BY num_store
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: The version I am using is sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query = """ select num_store, sum(gross_sales) as gross_sales from 
 dtm.sales where day = {input_date} and num_store = {input_store} GROUP BY 
 num_store """

dict = new Dict()
dict['input_date'] = datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d ')
dict['input_store'] = value
query.format(**dict)
```

Comment: It didn't work ! How to apply what you suggested to the first query which is inside Python not the second one that is being used to test directly against the database ?

Comment: what import to use for dict ?

Comment: @S.Jackson You dont need to import dictionary it is in standard lib

Comment: I used it and I get this error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: My date is only YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @S.Jackson Showed you a way to make your query work , but you need to convert your date string into datetime. If it works mark it as solved , thank you.

Comment: This approach is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do not know the defense mechanics here , so if this suggestion is so bad i can remove the answer. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a prepared statement:

```
import sqlite3

# obtain connection and cursor
sql = """select num_store, sum(gross_sales) as gross_sales
         from dtm.sales 
         where day = ? and num_store = ?
         group by num_store"""
params = (input_date, store,)
c.execute(sql, params)
# c.fetchall()
```

Using a prepared statement frees you from worrying about how to escape the literal values in your query.

Comment: Thanks ! But I need the sql request to stay the same for the sake of the whole project and the behavior of the django-rest-framework api I am developing

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your problem, you'll need to convert this 'ANSIDATE' in a string.
Your ANSIDATE follows this pattern '%Y-%m-%d' (yyyy-mm-dd) and you could do:

```
sql = "select num_store, sum(gross_sales) as gross_sales from dtm.sales where day = " + input_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ...
```

Comment: from where do you get .strftime ?? is there an import i should make ?

Comment: import datetime